# Inverse in distributional sense

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Suppose that $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and $xf_n\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$ in distributional sense (take for example $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+(1/n)^2}$). Prove that $f_n\to P.V.\frac{1}{x}$, where $P.V.\frac{1}{x}$ is the Cauchy Principal Value of $1/x$, defined by
$$
<P.V.\frac{1}{x},\phi>=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus[-\epsilon,\epsilon]}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}dx.
$$
Any help is appreciate.

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4851308/168433

Comment: No it is not. Here I'm asking for a general issue, there for a specific example.

Comment: Oh, I see... Well, I think that what you want to prove is not true. Take $g_n(x)=f_n(x)+d_n(x),$ where $d_n$ converges to $\delta.$ Remember that $x\delta=0.$

Comment: Yes, I see. In general I can only tell that it converges to $P.V.\frac{1}{x}+c\delta$, for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$. In this case particular case, $c=0$.

Comment: Correct. But if the functions in the sequence are odd, like $f_n,$ then we have $c=0$ since the limit must also be odd.

Comment: Yes, I proved it by testing on an even test function $\phi$ with $\phi(0)\neq0$.