# Distributional limit of functions

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Consider the sequence $\{g_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, $g_n(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+(1/n)^2}$. Prove that $g_n\to P.V.\frac{1}{x}$, where $P.V.\frac{1}{x}$ is the Cauchy Principal Value of $1/x$, defined by
$$
\left<P.V.\frac{1}{x},\phi\right>=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus[-\epsilon,\epsilon]}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}dx.
$$
Any help is appreciate.

Comment: I do understand the confusion or conflation but "functional calculus" has a well-defined meaning, at the very least in terms of the tag I removed: it applies to a mapping of the type $f \mapsto f(A)$ which assigns to certain functions $f$ an operator $f(A)$ which serves to "apply $f$ to the operator $A$" in a precise sense. This notion appears in spectral theory, especially for self-adjoint operators on Hilbert spaces. Anyway, sorry for the rambling, and have a nice day/night/whatever time it is for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $g_n \to PV \frac{1}{x}$ means that for any $φ\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$, we have
$$\langle g_n, φ\rangle \to \langle PV \frac{1}{x}, φ\rangle$$
or equivalently
$$a_n := \langle g_n - PV\frac{1}{x}, φ\rangle \to 0.$$
Writing out this term gives
$$\begin{align*}
a_n &= \lim_{ε\to 0} \left[ \int_{[-ε;ε]} \frac{x}{x^2 + 1/n^2} φ(x)dx + \int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus [-ε;ε]}\left(\frac{x}{x^2 + 1/n^2} - \frac{1}{x}\right)φ(x)dx \right] \\
&= \lim_{ε\to 0} \left[ \int_{[-ε;ε]} \frac{x}{x^2 + 1/n^2} φ(x)dx - \int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus [-ε;ε]}\frac{1}{x(n^2x^2 + 1)}φ(x)dx \right]
\end{align*}$$
For simpler notation, let $M = ||φ||_\infty$, i.e. the sup of $φ$. In absolute value we can hence bound
$$\begin{align*}
|a_n| 
&\leq \limsup_{ε\to 0} \left[ \int_{[-ε;ε]} \frac{|x|}{x^2 + 1/n^2} |φ(x)|dx + \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus [-ε;ε]}\frac{1}{n^2x^2 + 1}\frac{φ(x)}{x}dx \right|\right] \\
&\leq \limsup_{ε\to 0} \left[ εM\int_{[-ε;ε]} \frac{1}{x^2 + 1/n^2} dx + \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus [-ε;ε]}\frac{1}{n^2x^2 + 1}\frac{φ(x)}{x}dx \right|\right] \\
&= \limsup_{ε\to 0} \left[ 2εMn^2\arctan(n^2ε) + \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus [-ε;ε]}\frac{1}{n^2x^2 + 1}\frac{φ(x)}{x}dx \right|\right] \\
&\leq \limsup_{ε\to 0} \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus [-ε;ε]}\frac{1}{n^2x^2 + 1}\frac{φ(x)}{x}dx \right|
\end{align*}$$
and using that $PV\frac{1}{x}$ is well-defined, you can conclude that the last term $\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: What do you mean with using the fact that P.V.$\frac{1}{x}$ is well defined? You mean that it is bounded?

Comment: Well it isn't exactly bounded, but it is finite. The last term contains this $\int \varphi(x)/x$, and a factor involving $n$ which will make it small as $n\to\infty$.